# python 2 print array with float formatting and without line return

Tags: python, python-2.7, formatting, carriage-return

I am using Python 2.7
I ran into this formatting problem when trying to output some debug data.
I want to print only 5 decimal, have all result on the same line and separated by a tab

```
for index in range(NBR):
  print("%.5f\t," % (result[line, index]))
```

and it resulted in

```
5.68842,    
4.29441,    
6.27793,
```

while i wanted

```
5.68842    4.29441    6.27793
```

Any advise on how to remove this unwanted return line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's alright, i found the solution. it was simply missing the coma ',' at the end of the line and not within the string

```
print("%.5f\t" % (result[line, index])),
```